# Google Cloud Video Intelligence checking free monthy usage programatically

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I have been using Google Cloud Video Intelligence succesfully with my content with the following code for some time with my Django application running on Google App Engine Flex.

```
gs_video_path ='gs://'+bucket_name+'/'+videodata.video.path+videodata.video.name
video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
features = [videointelligence.enums.Feature.OBJECT_TRACKING]
operation = video_client.annotate_video(gs_video_path, features=features)
```

As explicitly stated by Google Cloud, each month the following is

```
Feature                     First 1000 minutes  Minutes 1000+

Label detection             Free                $0.10 / minute
Shot detection              Free                $0.05 / minute, or free with Label detection
Explicit content detection  Free                $0.10 / minute
Speech transcription        Free                $0.048 / minute 
Object tracking             Free                $0.15 / minute
Text detection              Free                $0.15 / minute
Logo recognition            Free                $0.15 / minute
Celebrity recognition       Free                $0.10 / minute
```

How can I programatically detect that the free first 1000 minutes has been used, or the current usage for these features at that instant ?

Comment: There is no way for you to make this automatically by relying on an API. You would need to keep track of the amount of minutes you have using and deduct them from the free minutes so that you send yourself a notification.

Comment: Thanks @rsalinas, that is exactly my understanding as well. Does first 1000 minutes refers to the thousand execution minutes of VideoIntelligence API? By the way, yout answer is the correct one, if you provide it as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Alright on more question, yes, I can count the minutes that I have been using. Yet, when does the 1000 minutes per month reset, is it resetting in every 1st day of the month at 00:00 GMT. There is zero information about this literally anywhere.

Comment: I think those particular details regarding the timing in which the quota is reset and such can only be provided by GCP Billing Support which you can contact [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing). Also, I think you can do the estimate of one of your cases with the [GCP Pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)

Comment: As correctly suggested here, I am contacting the GCP Billing Support to see when the 1000 minutes quota will be reset in terms of billing. I will share the information here when I receive the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to make this automatically by relying on an API. You would need to keep track of the amount of minutes you have using and deduct them from the free minutes so that you send yourself a notification.

Additionally, you can do the estimate of one of your cases with the [GCP Pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Although that is far from the answer that I am looking for, in reality this is the closes and most practical answer and frankly the actual truth, hence I am accepting this as correct.